# Bevel illusion using Illustrator or Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

[image]

I wanted to know if there's a quicker process to achieve this effect in Illustrator or Photoshop. What I did, I created a single curved edge and copied it along the sides of the heart. I was wondering if there's a plugin or a filter that mimic this effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I was able to find the plugin for illustrator, it's called Afternow by Scriptographer

http://scriptographer.org/gallery/afternow/comments